# How to proof $ \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}d\ f_{+}^{'}(t)\ d\ s = \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)_{+}d\ f_{+}^{'}(t) $?

Tags: calculus

How to proof the following equation,
$$
\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{s}d\ f_{+}^{'}(t)\ d\ s = \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)_{+}d\ f_{+}^{'}(t).
$$
Here, $(x-b)_{+} = max{x-b, 0}$; $f_{+}^{'}$ denotes the right derivative of $f$.

Comment: Your notations are not clear but this should be immediate from Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that $g_+$ means $\max\{g,0\}$.  Let $\chi_E$ be the indicator function of a set $E$.  If $P$ is the subset of $[0,x]$ on which $f'>0$, then
$$\int_0^sdf'_+(t)=\int_0^x\chi_P(t)\ \chi_{[0,s]}(t)\ df'(t).$$
By Fubini's theorem, we get
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df_+'(t)\ ds=\int_0^x\int_0^x\chi_P(t)\ \chi_{[0,s]}(t)\ df'(t)\ ds=\int_0^x\int_0^x \chi_{[0,s]}(t)\ ds\ \chi_P(t)\ df'(t).$$
Therefore,
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df'_+(t)\ ds=\int_0^x\int_0^x\chi_{[t,x]}(s)\ ds\ \chi_P(t)\ df'(t)=\int_0^x\int_t^x ds\ \chi_P(t)\ df'(t).$$
Consequently,
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df'_+(t)\ ds=\int_0^x(x-t)\ \chi_P(t)\ df'(t)=\int_0^x(x-t)\ df'_+(t).$$
But as $x\geq t$ for all $t\in[0,x]$, $(x-t)=(x-t)_+$, and
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df'_+(t)\ ds=\int_0^x(x-t)_+\ df'_+(t).$$

---

*Edit after OP's correction*

If $P$ is the subset of $[0,x]$ on which $f'>0$, then
$$\int_0^sdf'_+(t)=\int_0^x\chi_{[0,s]}(t)\ df'_+(t).$$
By Fubini's theorem, we get
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df_+'(t)\ ds=\int_0^x\int_0^x\chi_{[0,s]}(t)\ df_+'(t)\ ds=\int_0^x\int_0^x \chi_{[0,s]}(t)\ ds\ df_+'(t).$$
Therefore,
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df'_+(t)\ ds=\int_0^x\int_0^x\chi_{[t,x]}(s)\ ds\ df'_+(t)=\int_0^x\int_t^x ds\ df_+'(t).$$
Consequently,
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df'_+(t)\ ds=\int_0^x(x-t)\ df'_+(t).$$
But as $x\geq t$ for all $t\in[0,x]$, $(x-t)=(x-t)_+$, and
$$\int_0^x\int_0^s df'_+(t)\ ds=\int_0^x(x-t)_+\ df'_+(t)=\int_0^\infty(x-t)_+\ df'_+(t).$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry for not stating the problem clearly. Here, $(x-b)_{+} = max{x-b, 0}$; $f_{+}^{'}$ denotes the right derivative of $f$.  How should I proof with these definations?

Comment: @XinyuanWei I don't understand why you need $(x-t)_+$ when you integrate from $t=0$ to $t=x$.  Shouldn't $(x-t)_+=(x-t)$ there?  Is there something I missed?

Comment: @XinyuanWei But if you were writing $$\int_0^x\int_0^sdf'_+(t)\ ds=\int_0^{\color{red}\infty}(x-t)_+\ df'_+(t),$$ then everything makes sense.

Comment: I am also wondering why there is a positive part function. It is from Optimal Reinsurance under VaR and CVaR Risk Measures: A Simplified Approach, Lemma 3.1, in the following link https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1578622

Comment: The proof is basically unaltered.  I just didn't have to use $\chi_P$ anymore (not that it was ever necessary to be there in the first proof I gave).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.